# How programs that look into different kinds of "database-like" file types coded?

Tags: c#, database, file, file-extension

Sorry, im not familiar with stackoverflow and I dont know how to put it into words, i.e. what are these programs called.

anyway, im talking about game files, I see people have made such stuff as "fan-work" without knowlodge of whats "actually" in these files.

Im talking about the programs that extract, for example, lets call, .bin files and such, you extract a file and it extracts 50 .jpg files, 120 .xml files and the person who made that program didnt even know what "exactly" was in it. only had an idea.

I tried to open such files with hex editors, and I only saw %0.5 or less, a few readable words and rest is trash.

Im going to tag this question languages and stuff im familiar with because I dont actually know what Im talking about, and merely looking for a tiny light in a void of darkness. **I BEG YOU** please fix this question and tell me what im trying to tell.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, not only do we code, we mind read too!

Comment: I am guessing the poster is asking how do programs (like ResHacker for example) work, maybe I am right and the poster can clarify that? Then we might be able to help them

Comment: http://oi40.tinypic.com/ekey6d.jpg I mean like this, its from a program that reads files of a game. all these stuff is read from a single file, contained in a single file, there are many extensions within it. how did he do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Many file formats can actually be recognized by [Magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number), i.e. a sequence of characteristic bytes, mostly at the beginning of the file. Especially on Unixoid systems, the *file extension* (e.g. `*.jpg`) is of less importance, and applications rely on actual detection, often via the [`file` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29). Such a heuristic is already capable of detecting quite a number of (common, well-known) file formats.